# Accessing a member in the hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a JSON that controller generates and in debug window it looks like this:

[image]

So basically this hash has two main elements, one is `medications` and one is `query_duration`. And medications its self is has a few members. 
To draw some charts I need to pass the whole Medications part of this to the Javascript, I used GON gem for passing to JavaScript.  But my problem is that I don't know how to pass the medications part? 
Should I say like `@order_summary[0]`  `@order_summary.medications`  ? none of them worked tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@order_summary['medications']
```

Should work.